# Existence and uniqueness for SDE 2D linear system

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

I have the  following SDE $$\ddot{x} +x = \dot{B(t)}$$

with some given initial condition $(x_0,\dot{x_0})$ and where $B(t)$ is a standard Brownian motion. I can reduce it to first order by introducing the variable  $y(t)= \dot{x}(t)$.

Hence the system writes

$$ 
d \vec{x} = A \vec{x}dt + \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix} dB(t)
$$

and $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\-1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
I want to show existence and uniqueness for such a SDE, (i.e. I want to show Lipschitz condition and linear growth), but I don't know how to do because usually I have a scalar SDE, while now I have to write it as a system of first order SDEs.

How can I move? I have never faced such a 2dimensional case.

Comment: Write out the LHS of the system as a vector and ensure existence and uniqueness for every entry in the vector. This gives existence and uniqueness for the entire system.

Comment: could you elaborate your comment in an answer? I've not understood

Comment: I don't know anything specific about SDE's, so I don't feel comfortable giving an answer. Usually when dealing with systems of differential equations, they are actually vector differential equations, which is why evaluating it entry-wise is a possibility if you are not familiar with higher-dimensional differential equations.

Comment: Ok, but here the systems is coupled, even if it's linear... I can't prove entry-wise existence and uniqueness

Comment: That makes sense. Have you attempted to show that the system satisfies a Lipschitz condition, and do you know about matrix-norms?

Comment: Yes I'm familiar with them, but never used to prove existence and uniqueness. How can I start?

Comment: Using the Frobenius norm as an example we have that $||Ax||_F \leq ||A||_F ||x||$. Hopefully this could help with finding your Lipschitz constant.

Comment: To show lipschtiz conditions I can do $||Ax-Ay)|| = ||A(x-y)|| \leq ||A|| ||x-y||$. 

I should also show linear growth, but I don't know if in the sdes system context it is the same in the ode case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific example you do not need SDE theory for the stated purposes. To that end, use $y=\dot x-B$ as second state variable, then
\begin{align}
\dot x(t) &= y(t)+B(t)\\
\dot y(t) &=  -x(t)
\end{align}
is an linear ODE system with continuous inhomogeneity (assuming you take a pathwise continuous realization of the Brownian motion, as is usually done).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought I had to prove lipschitz condition and linear growth, maybe using matricial norms.  So in practice you're reating $t \mapsto B(t)$ as a general linear function (in this case nowhere differentiable) right?

Comment: $t\mapsto B(\omega,t)$ is for any fixed $\omega$ of the probability space a continuous function. Thus the ODE existence and uniqueness theorems apply for every $\omega$ separately. You might still have to invoke the SDE theory if you want to use claims on statistical properties. Then you get the cited conditions from the fact that the system is linear.